# What does the .x function on nvd3 implements?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to start using the nvd3.js library but not been able to find any documentation. 
On the [cumulativeLine](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/cumulativeLine.html) for example
where can I research about the various functions like .x .y etc. ? Are those nvd3 specific or
they are d3 functions ?
Is there a clear distinction on which of the code represents d3 functionality and which nvd3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you are referring to are D3 functions that are documented [on the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference). As a general rule, anything that you don't find in the D3 documentation is probably nvd3.